# Time series analysis - Seasonal variation problem

Tags: r, regression, time-series, seasonality, longitudinal-data-analysis

[image]

I am having trouble with taking out seasonal problem in the data. 
If you see the picture, the error messg saying "non-numeric argument to binary operator". How should I fix this problem?

Comment: It appears your data at `dz$seasonal` is not numeric, or probably it's the NA's that are causing trouble, since you cannot subtract NA. You should use an in-built function for differenceinf, such as `diff()`

Answer (score 2):

You are subtracting `dz$seasonal` from `dz`. We can't tell for sure, since you did not include your data (e.g., using `dput()`), but as the result from `decompose()`, `dz` must be a `list` with multiple components, and you can't subtract a vector (`dz$seasonal`) from a `list`.

Do `dz$x-dz$seasonal` instead, since `dz$x` contains the original series. For example:

```
> dz <- decompose(co2)
> dz$x-dz$seasonal
          Jan      Feb      Mar      Apr      May      Jun      Jul      Aug      Sep      Oct      Nov      Dec
1959 315.4736 315.6994 315.1244 315.0432 315.1297 315.6708 315.5771 315.9005 316.7346 316.4319 316.7297 316.3951
1960 316.3236 316.1994 316.0444 316.3532 316.8697 317.1008 317.1971 316.9905 317.0546 316.9319 316.9097 316.9951
```

See `?decompose`.

Answer (score 0):

With the `decompose()` command you calculate the trend by an Moving Average (The mean in a specific window around time t(x)). For this it is unavoidable to loose some information at the beginning/end. You could just use all Values between 2014m7 and 2016m6.

(Are you sure there is a seasonal effect? All Values in the seasonal component are very small. If you don´t need this effect you wouldn´t loose the data points.)

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @StephanKolassa If I want to eliminate seasonality and trend effect on the variable, should I code it like "dz$x-dz$seasonal-dz$trend" ? or it doesn't make sense ?

Comment: @SooMinShin: yes, you can do `dz$x-dz$seasonal-dz$trend`. Or simply `dz$random`, which gives the exact same result.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Thanks for the help!! Also, do you know when or what kind of variable needs to take out trend effect ?

Comment: `dz$trend` should do what you want. Also, you could look at [STL decomposition](https://otexts.org/fpp2/stl.html).